# Does deleting the "build" folder on every deploy have an effect in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a react app created using create-react-app. When I deploy, I build in the /build folder and then move the contents to /dist, where the server serves the app. If I build the app locally, the building takes 50 seconds because I always delete the /build folder to save space on my pc. But if I don't delete the /build folder it takes 600 seconds.

If I delete the build folder on every deploy, does it affect the performance of my app?

Comment: How big is your app?  If you are just starting with React and building small programs your build time should be minimal (a couple of seconds) even without deleting the build folder.  Perhaps what you are really asking is "why is my build time so long and what might I do to speed it up?"

Answer (score -1):

welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't think it affects the performance of your application. I think it is also a good way to ensure your build have all the latest changes and updates you have done on the code. Cheers